# How to work with filesystem in a smart and clean way

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, fs

I am learning to manipulate files with javascript using the "fs" module. I would like to know what is the best way to handle exceptions, or perform better the reading and writing functions, for example:

I need to read all the files from a directory and write all the contents of the files into a single file, moreover I need the files to be written in the correct order based on their names.

I'm doing it this way:

```js
function readAllLogs() {
    const allLogsPathDir = dirPathOfAllLogs
    const logPathFile = filePathOfAllLogs

    fs.writeFile(logPathFile, "", function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Err')
        }
    })

    var files = []
    fs.readdirSync(allLogsPathDir).forEach(function (file) {
        files.push(file)
    });
    
    setTimeout((async function () {
        for (var index in files) {
            const data = fs.readFileSync(allLogsPathDir + files[index], 'utf8')
            fs.appendFileSync(logPathFile, data, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`File: ERR!`)
                }
                console.log(`File: OK!`)
            })
        }
    }), 2000);

    return files
}
```

This code works for me, but I would like to understand how to work with "fs" in a smart and clean way, not only for this case but for all the cases that arise in my journey.

Comment: What's the point of the timeout and the `async` function?

Comment: I'm using the timeout because this part of the code depends on the variable files

Comment: But you're synchronously filling that array. (Btw, you could've just written `const files = fs.readdirSync(allLogsPathDir);`). If there was something asynchronous about that call, using a timeout would be the worst way to cope with that.

Comment: How can I make writing and reading occur with exception handling? Should I separate part by part in a function and use Promise().then(createFile).then(readDirAndWriteInFile) or something like this

Comment: If you want to keep it simple and synchronous, drop the `setTimeout`, drop the callback argument to [`fs.appendFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options), and also make the initial truncation of the file synchronous. If you want to make it asynchronous, use `fs.promises` (or promisify each method individually), then write a `then` chain or use `await`s. I'm not sure how you'd handle exceptions other than by logging them and stopping your program, you can do that using `try`/`catch` (sync or async/await) or `.catch()` (for the `then` chain).

Comment: Thank you, Bergi. I created 3 function to read, write and append all my files, then I use async/await. I don't know if is the best way but it's very clean now. The try catch works very well for me. Thanks again